# how can I generate a json return for all the objects in a twilio call

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra, twilio

This is similar to a question I asked recently but meaningfully different. Using ruby, sinatra and twilio I want to get call log records as a json object so that I can then print it ona n HTML page. My code is:

```
get '/call_logs' do
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
calls = client.account.calls.list
calls.each do |call|
@sid = call.sid
puts @sid
@from = call.from
puts @from
@to = call.to
puts @to
@price = call.price.to_s
puts @price
@duration = call.duration
puts @duration
end
halt 200, {sid:@sid,from:@from,to:@to,price:@price,duration:@duration}.to_json
end
```

This produces only one return which is:

```
{
   "sid":"CAdd102cb19729424b1acdbe7b93a03400",
   "from":"+441903684027",
   "to":"+818088931617",
   "price":"-0.16000",
   "duration":"16"
}
```

There are, in fact, multiple records but I am only getting one. If I place

```
{
    sid:@sid,
    from:@from,
    to:@to,
    price:@price,
    duration:@duration
}.to_json
```

within the "calls.each" loop I get an error so I am stuck. In the terminal multiple records appear but only one as json. So, my question is how can I improve this code to get all the records returned as json?

I have tried with and without "halt 200".

Many thanks for your help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance variables are overwritten in each loop iteration. You need to keep/store each iteration in array and in the end convert that array to json. Please try below mentioned code. It will work fine.

```
get '/call_logs' do
  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
  calls = client.account.calls.list
  @result = []
  calls.each do |call|
    sc = {}
    sc[:sid] = call.sid
    puts sc[:sid]
    sc[:from] = call.from
    puts sc[:from]
    sc[:to] = call.to
    puts sc[:to]
    sc[:price] = call.price.to_s
    puts sc[:price]
    sc[:duration] = call.duration
    puts sc[:duration]
    @result << sc
  end
  halt 200, @result.to_json
end
```

Comment: brilliant, works great thank you. Thank you too for the explanation about storing in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your class variables on each loop iteration. Try this:

```
calls.map do |call|
  {
    :sid => call.sid,
    :from => call.from,
    :to => call.to,
    :price => call.price,
    :duration => call.duration
  } # accumulating records in array
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: absolutely AWESOME - very economic code and perfect, thank you. I am not sure who responded first (both say 10 minutes ago) but I will have to tick the other one though because it seems that it was entered first and also works. But this is wonderful and will allow me to generalize with this method, I am very grateful.

Comment: You are welcome. You are free to tick whatever you want, JFYI: the answer entered later goes to appear on top on SO.

Comment: I got it the wrong way round, sorry. Both answers are great.